# SQL group result in "sequence"

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a database (MySQL) with a table like this:

Column definition :

```
ID (pk , long , auto_increment) ,
raw_data (double) ,
numDevice (int) ,
numVar (int) ,
timemillis (long)  , 
date (timestamp)
```

example of data :

```
ID |RAW_DATA           |numDevice | numVar |TIMEMILLIS   |   TIMESTAMP
 01| 86.23775482177734 |    1     | 1      |1424180019706|2015-02-17 13:33:39
 02| 91.85794067382812 |    1     | 1      |1424180022857|2015-02-17 13:34:42
 03| 88.02635192871094 |    1     | 1      |1424180026008|2015-02-17 13:35:46
 04| 89.89857482910156 |    1     | 1      |1424180029159|2015-02-17 15:22:49
 05| 86.82943725585938 |    1     | 1      |1424180035460|2015-02-17 15:23:55
 06| 93.07737731933594 |    1     | 1      |1424180038613|2015-02-17 15:24:58
 07| 87.77403259277344 |    1     | 1      |1424180041764|2015-02-17 18:34:01
 08| 92.69800567626953 |    1     | 1      |1424180044915|2015-02-17 18:34:04
 09| 90.60401916503906 |    1     | 1      |1424180048067|2015-02-17 18:34:08
 10| 88.20098876953125 |    1     | 1      |1424180051218|2015-02-17 18:34:11
```

...........

I search a query  to group results by date that follows with maximum 1 minute interval for example , this query should have for result  :

Group 1 :

```
 01| 86.23775482177734 |    1     | 1      |1424180019706|2015-02-17 13:33:39
 02| 91.85794067382812 |    1     | 1      |1424180022857|2015-02-17 13:34:42
 03| 88.02635192871094 |    1     | 1      |1424180026008|2015-02-17 13:35:46
```

Group 2 :

```
 04| 89.89857482910156 |    1     | 1      |1424180029159|2015-02-17 15:22:49
 05| 86.82943725585938 |    1     | 1      |1424180035460|2015-02-17 15:23:55
 06| 93.07737731933594 |    1     | 1      |1424180038613|2015-02-17 15:24:58
```

Group 3

```
 07| 87.77403259277344 |    1     | 1      |1424180041764|2015-02-17 18:34:01
 08| 92.69800567626953 |    1     | 1      |1424180044915|2015-02-17 18:34:04
 09| 90.60401916503906 |    1     | 1      |1424180048067|2015-02-17 18:34:08
 10| 88.20098876953125 |    1     | 1      |1424180051218|2015-02-17 18:34:11
```

It's been two days since I search on the net without success, any help is welcome. thank you

Comment: There is a definitional problem.  Your Groups 1 and 2 each span more than 2 minutes.  Even after getting past that, what would you do if 100 readings came regularly at 40-second intervals?  Would that be one "group"?

Comment: SQL has no way (other than WITH ROLLUP) to put breaks between 'groups' of output rows.  Consider doing your task in a real programming language (PHP, Java, Perl, VB, etc).

Comment: Thank you for your response, In fact is a java program that allows for the monitoring on a water pipeline.

the pipeline is filled several times a day (this is the "group" I talk about in the previous question) , the column raw_data represents the water flow in the pipe. my program need to  display a list  with the different periods ( beginning and end) when the pipeline was active :

for example the pipe was filled from  13:33:39  to 13:35:46 ; from 15:22:49 to 15:24:58 and from 18:34:01 to 18:34:11 

I can do it directly in Java , but I wondered if it were possible to do so via a SQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider, instead, one line per "group":

```
SELECT  CONCAT(MIN(id), '-', MAX(id)) AS id_range,
        SUM(RAW_DATA) AS sum_raw_data,
        CONCAT(MIN(TIMESTAMP), ' - ', RIGHT(MAX(TIMESTAMP), 8)) AS time_span
    FROM  tbl
    GROUP BY  LEFT(TIMESTAMP, 15);
```

That should give you something like:

```
01-03   266.666666   2015-02-17 13:33:39 - 13:35:46
04-06   277.888888   ...
```

Comment: Thank you , I  had not thought to do so by concatenation , it works , thanks again

Comment: There is a caveat -- If the "group" spills across a 10-minute boundary, it will be split into two groups.  Perhaps you can live with that.